# Random, default, functions not working in R (freq_terms() yesterday, tokens() today)

Tags: r

I think i'm going crazy here. I'm working on some code for an assignment in r. Machine learning, so i have a bit of data but i've limited myself to 500 records for now to get it working. 
Yet this weekend i ran into something really stupid, R suddenly couldn't remember that it had a `freq_terms()` function and told me that the function didn't exist.
Since it was only used to make an overview of most frequent terms used it wasn't a major deal.

Yet today that part of the code (that i didn't change) works again. Hooray! Only now Rstudio tells me that tokens() doesn't exist... and that's a big problem since i do need that function a lot!

This is the code and error:

```
reviewtokens <- tokens(Merged_Kaggle_Data$Merged_Review, what="word", remove_numbers=TRUE, remove_punct=TRUE, remove_symbols=TRUE, remove_hyphens=TRUE)
Error in tokens(Merged_Kaggle_Data$Merged_Review, what = "word", remove_numbers = TRUE,  : 
  could not find function "tokens"
```

It worked fine on my desktop yesterday evening, today it doesn't work at all and i didn't change anything in that code.

library list:

```
library(biclust)
library(caret)
library(DBI)
library(dendextend)
library(dplyr)
library(e1071)
library(fpc)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)
library(igraph)
library(irlba)
library(plotrix)
library(qdap)
library(quanteda)
library(randomForest)
library(Rcampdf)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(reshape2)
library(RMySQL)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(RWeka)
library(SnowballC)
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(glmnet)
```

Comment: Are you loading the correct libraries when you start a new session? Ideally, you should load all the libraries you need at the top of your analysis script.

Comment: Yeah i do, but tokens() should be a default function in R (as far as i could tell) i added my library list just in case

Comment: `tokens()` is not a built-in function, as far as I know. You can see which libraries provide it by  typing `??tokens` in the console. I don't have any libraries that contain a `tokens()` function currently.

Comment: Thanks @Marius ! somewhere in changing from desktop to laptop my libraries got mixed up. I downloaded all of them again, ran them about 10 times and now tokens() works again. You're the best.

Comment: Neither `tokens` nor `freq_terms` is part of base R. `tokens` is in  `quanteda` (which you load) and `freq_terms` in  `qdap`, which you also load. Maybe re-installing these libraries may hhelp?